# DAISY player with GUI

Tags: linux, open-source, media-player, audiobook, daisy

I need an audio player that supports the [DAISY Digital Talking Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAISY_Digital_Talking_Book) standard.

I don’t require how much of the standard it has to support (the more, the better) as long as it allows me

- to navigate the audiobook structure, and
- to play/pause the audio, obviously.

The tool must have a GUI. (I only know [daisy-player](http://www.jlemmens.nl/homepage/uk/daisy-player/daisy-player.html), but it’s for the command-line.)

It must be FLOSS and run on GNU/Linux (ideally available from Debian’s package sources).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like DaisyDuck does what you need it too. It's open source and contains a GUI interface for playing Daisy Digital audiobooks. It provides an audiobook navigation structure and allows you to pause the audio as well. It also is compatible with both Windows and Linux (note: the Linux version is more updated than the Windows).

## [DaisyDuck project](http://daisy.geexbox.org/INTRODUCTION.en.html) (open source)

> The goal of this project is to provide the playback of online books and the playback of local books (reachable directly on a physical media). The interface is simplified for a quick handling, even for people with an handicap like partially sighted persons.
>   Intuitive keyboard shortcuts provide an easy way in order to access the functionalities of the application and in order to navigate in the books (by chapter and by paragraph). DaisyDuck saves automatically the position where the playback of a book was interrupted. Then, when this book is reloaded, the start of the playback begins on the last position, without any action of the auditor.
>
> [image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Do you know a good player for Android?